Plot times-series with mean line and and min and max in r with datetime hourly data
I have 5 years of data for the months of June - Sept for three hourly variables in a dataframe that looks like this:
structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1559347200, 1559350800, 
1559354400, 1559358000, 1559361600, 1559365200, 1559368800, 1559372400, 
1559376000, 1559379600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), BUSwt = c(77.8154, 77.2538, 76.9325, 76.81235, 76.6544, 
76.3403, 76.16165, 76.22375, 76.47035, 76.74395), MBwt = c(78.3653, 
78.53495, 78.6074, 78.30725, 78.0368, 77.9477, 77.8946, 77.927, 
78.12455, 78.23615), SUSwt = c(76.2575, 76.0055, 75.7265, 75.425, 
75.137, 74.849, 74.651, 74.624, 74.696, 74.8535)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

I would like to summarize and plot the  each of the mean hourly variablesas well as their min and max for the 5 year span so that it would look similar to this:

Is there a way I can do this?

You are missing a line in your toy data. We cannot copy and run. What have you tried? Please note: so is no code writing service.

Corrected sorry about that

The mean, min, and max of 5 years of hourly data will just be 3 values. If you're looking to plot a rolling average/min/max, you should compute those first and then create the plot.

Ok so how would I go about doing that for the three variables?

Several packages can help with rolling calculations including zoo and slider. If you are working with a data.table, there are builtin functions.

I think the gets to what you are looking for, convert the data to a long format, summarise mean/max/min for each variable and then plot means as a line and min/max as a ribbon.
library(tidyverse)

#make a second day of data

df_2 <- data.frame(datetime=df$datetime+days(1), BUSwt=df$BUSwt*sample(c(0.9,1.1), 1, replace = T), MBwt=df$MBwt*sample(c(0.9,1.1), 1, replace = T), SUSwt=df$SUSwt*sample(c(0.9,1.1), 1, replace = T))

#combine days and convert to long format
df_long <- df %>%
  bind_rows(df_2) %>%
    
  pivot_longer(cols = BUSwt:SUSwt, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value")


#summarise each variable by date
df_daily_summary <- df_long %>%
  mutate(Date=as.Date(datetime)) %>%
  group_by(Date, Variable) %>%
  summarise(Mean=mean(Value, na.rm=T),
            Max=max(Value, na.rm=T),
            Min=min(Value, na.rm=T))


#plot the data with line for mean and ribbon for min/max
df_daily_summary %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Mean)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(Date, ymin=Min, ymax = Max), alpha=0.5)+labs(y="Value")+
  geom_line()+facet_wrap(~Variable, nrow=3)

